# how to deallocate memory spaces in Java. ?

Tags: java, android, performance, optimization

I am working on an enhancement project which had an issue, " The process of the android app is slowed proportionally as the usage of app is increased" I figured out the reason for the slow process is accumulation of data in cache memory, which is not cleared after the particular session is closed(i.e the cache memory remains even after the app is closed.). Since the app is developed in Java I couldn't use Destructor to clear the memory space. 
Can any one suggest the possible way to deallocate the memory space.?

Comment: What cache memory? Do you have programatic access to it? If not, then **no**; you can't do anything with it. In fact, if it's keeping memory after your app is closed, I doubt there's anything you can do to fix it.

Comment: Java has a garbage collector. You shouldn't care about memory-realted issues. If your program has bad performance, the problem probably lies somewhere else.

Comment: The memory spaces allocated for objects, and media files like(audio and  images) were being processed dynamically while our app is being processed. These are the only possible memory consuming functions in our app. while analyzing the memory consuption during the process we figured out the cache memory has 90-120 MB of data after the app is closed (While starting the app for first time it is supposed to be 30 MB)and it is not cleared when the app is reopened. @Impulse The Fox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java uses Grabage Collector, Hence the Allocated Memory for an object would free up when there are no Strong Reference to that object, It seems there are two problems with project you are working on, It may suffers from Memory Leaks, which would occurr when the developer leaves a strong reference to an object that who doesn't need anymore, Like a Handler, Or a Reference from a short lived-object to a static object or the main class objects. You can use the Eclipse MAT tool for detecting these memory leaks.

The other problem seems to be the cache mechanism that doesn't free up its memeory footprint, If it's an in house developed cache system, you need to debug it. It's recommend to use an open soured cache library and set a maximum memory usage limit.